# Does MVC Extensions grid support polymorphism?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, telerik, polymorphism, telerik-grid, telerik-mvc

Is it possible to take advantage of a polymorphic viewmodel when using the grid from MVC Extensions? Google wasn't very helpful :(

I know that ASP.NET MVC supports it via display templates. But how would I do something similar using the telerik grid?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it does.

http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-mvc/telerik-ui-components-grid-display-and-editor-templates.html

Hope this helps someone google it a bit easier :)